# Building Matrix via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am using two query from a schema which counts companies, but I am struggling how to combine them give Columns as Country and Industry as row and give the company counts accordingly.

```
select g.simpleindustrydescription,  count(c.companyid) as companycount from ciqcompany c
join ciqsimpleindustry g on g.simpleIndustryid = c.simpleIndustryid
join ciqbusinessdescription b on b.companyid = c.companyid
group by g.simpleindustrydescription

select g.country,  count(c.companyid) as companycount from ciqcompany c
join ciqcountrygeo g on g.countryid = c.countryid
join ciqbusinessdescription b on b.companyid = c.companyid     
group by g.country
```

**Expected Output:**

```
             Country A   Country B   Country C
Industry A       5         5           6
Industry B       3         3           4
Industry C       4         8           6
```

Comment: Give us an example of the expected output for sample data

Comment: provide more details about what do you want to achieve

Comment: By Country (Vertical Title) and Industry (Horizontal Title), and counts in the matrix

Comment: how do i attached a screen shot?

Comment: Thanks Dij and David Brabant, this is the output I am expecting

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of real example data, here a simple pivot example basing on some dummy records:

```
CREATE TABLE #tCountry
(
   ID INT
  ,Name NVARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #tCountry VALUES (1, 'Country A'), (2, 'Country B'), (3, 'Country C');

CREATE TABLE #tIndustry
(
   ID INT
  ,Name NVARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #tIndustry VALUES (1, 'Industry A'), (2, 'Industry B'), (3, 'Industry C');


CREATE TABLE #tMapping
(
   ID INT
  ,CountryID INT
  ,IndustryID INT
  ,Name NVARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #tMapping VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'Country A Industry A - 1'), (2, 1, 1, 'Country A Industry A - 2');
INSERT INTO #tMapping VALUES (3, 1, 2, 'Country A Industry B - 1'), (4, 1, 2, 'Country A Industry b - 2'), (5, 1, 2, 'Country A Industry b - 3');
INSERT INTO #tMapping VALUES (6, 2, 1, 'Country B Industry A - 1');

DECLARE @lCountries NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @lCountries += N', ' + QUOTENAME(CountryName)
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT tc.Name CountryName
  FROM #tCountry tc
  JOIN #tMapping tm ON tm.CountryID = tc.ID
) x;

SELECT @lCountries = STUFF(@lCountries, 1, 2, '');

SELECT @stmt = 'SELECT *
                  FROM
                  (
                  SELECT ti.Name IndustryName, tc.Name CountryName, COUNT(*) MappingCounter
                    FROM #tMapping tm
                    JOIN #tCountry tc ON tm.CountryID = tc.ID
                    JOIN #tIndustry ti ON tm.IndustryID = ti.ID
                    GROUP BY ti.Name, tc.Name
                  ) t
                  PIVOT (MAX(t.MappingCounter) FOR CountryName in (' + @lCountries + ')) AS x';

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt
```

Anyways, if you are dealing with an unknown number of countries, you might want to extend this example a little and use dynamic SQL in order to build the pivot statement. Got an example somewhere, but would have to search for it...

Result of my example:

```
IndustryName    Country A   Country B   Country C
Industry A      2           1           NULL
Industry B      3           NULL        NULL
```

Comment: HI, Yes the countries and Industry type is pulled from a separate table. I am trying to find a way to first split the company count into industry type for one country and then extend it to all countries. if Country A count is 100, I want first split that into Industry A - 20, Industry B - 20 ... based on my table